# 'Undefined index: submit' happens

Tags: php, mysql

The error message is:Notice: Undefined index: submit in G:\wamp64\www\mysql\index2.php on line 2.
I've set submit in the input session. Why this happens?

```
<?php

if ($_POST['submit']) {

    if(!$_POST['email']) $error.="<br>Please enter your email";
        else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $error.="<br>Please enter a valid email address";

    if(!$_POST['password']) $error.="<br>Please enter your password";
        else {
            if(strlen($_POST['password'])<8) $error.="<br>Please enter a password at least 8 characters";
            if(!preg_match('`[A-Z]`',$_POST['password'])) $error.="<br>Please enter at least one Big character in your password";

        }
    if($error) echo "<br>There were errors in your sign up details";
        else{
            $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
            $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email'])."'";

        }

}
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
<input type="submit" value="Sign In" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:-

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
```

Do:-

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Best would be check form values directly rather than submit checking

```
if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
```

Note:- your query is open for `SQL Injection`. So read about `prepared statements` of `mysqli` and use them. They will take care of everything like escaping as well as security loopholes.